# Error like "event.srcElement is undefined" in Firefox, working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, dom-events

I have a code below, this is working in both IE, Chrome but Firefox is not supporting, I am getting error like:

> event.srcElement is undefined

```
function(event){
    event = event || window.event;  
    var elem =event.srcElement.innerText;
    if( elem == "Add"){
        thisobj.previewSelected = false;
        dijit.byId("frmdlgpop").buttonGroup.getItemAt(0).attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `srcElement` to `target`. srcElement was implemented for IE and is non-standard.